# intergral $\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty }{ \sqrt { \frac { x+2 }{ { x }^{ 4 }-1 } } dx } $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

This question has been killing me,

> $$\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{ \sqrt { \frac { x+2 }{ { x }^{ 4 }-1 }  } dx } $$

Show that this is either divergent or convergent

Comment: Any improper integral is "either divergent or convergent".  You want to either show that it is divergent or show that it is convergent.

Comment: Yes however I am cannot bound it above or find a divergent function which is below this.

Comment: @DavidFairbairn Think about equivalence $\sim $ criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $1^+$,

$$x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1) $$

hence

$$\sqrt {\frac {x+2}{x^4-1}}\sim \sqrt { \frac {3}{4 (x-1)}} $$

thus it converges near $ 1^+$ because
$\int_1\frac {dx}{\sqrt {x-1}} $ converges.

As it converges near $+\infty $, (see DeepSea's above answer),
it is convergent.

Comment: I've proposed an answer which bounds the integral above.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\sqrt{\dfrac{x+2}{x^4+1}}\approx x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$. Use the $p$ series test with $p > 1$.

Comment: I see that it must be convergent from this however notice the minus on the bottom of the fraction so I cannot bound this above by root((x+2)/(x^4))

Comment: that is near infinity.

Comment: minus 3 over 2.$x^4-1$ not $x^4+1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }\frac{\sqrt(x+2)}{\sqrt(x^4 -1)}dx < \int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }\frac{\sqrt(4x)}{\sqrt(\frac{1}{4}x^4 )}dx = \int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }\frac{4}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

Which converges. Therefore by comparison the integral convergences.